# n_dead_tup same as it was before VACUUM FULL

Tags: postgresql

Today I noticed that saving operations into one of the table is so slow. I ran query `select n_live_tup, n_dead_tup, relname from pg_stat_all_tables` and found info that my table has 3 336 as `n_live_tup` and 46 508 837 as `n_dead_tup`. I guess it's because of UPSERT operations almost every minute. I tried to run `VACUUM FULL` on this table (before i stopped all operations with this table), but `n_dead_tup` still the same. `VACUUM FULL` took about 1 minute and was completed succesfully. But why `n_dead_tup` and also table size still the same as it was?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the possible reasons why `VACUUM` won't clean up dead tuples in [this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/reasons-why-vacuum-wont-remove-dead-rows/). The same holds for `VACUUM (FULL)` even though it operates differently.

1. There is a long-running transaction that either has a transaction ID (it modified something) or operates on the `REPEATABLE READ` or `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level. Note that those transactions will keep `VACUUM (FULL)` from removing dead tuples *even if they don't touch the table at all*.
2. There could be a stale replication slot. Check `pg_replication_slots` for slots that are not active.
3. There could be an orphaned prepared transaction; check `pg_prepared_xacts`.
4. There could be a standby server with `not_standby_feedback = on` that is running a very long query or has a very old `REPEATABLE READ` transaction.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `VACUUM FULL` doesn't refresh rows states. Or maybe i wrong, and it's doesn't refresh table statistics... Don't remember. =) Anyway try to make `VACUUM` instead.